# Does the Magna Eclipsis shield use elemental resistances?

Tags: path-of-exile

The Magna Eclipsis shield triggers Elemental Aegis on equip, that is a 1000 points shield against elemental damage.

From the item description: *Elemental Damage from Hits is taken from the Aegis before your Life or Energy Shield*

The question is: is the damage taken by the aegis calculated before or after the character's elemental resistances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short anserw: After.

Long anserw: There is a strict mechanics on how damage is calculated, as follow:

**1. Initial damage**

Damage sources have a base damage that can be increased by various stats. Stats are only applied once per calculation.

•  Flat damage

- Local modifiers apply to base damage on the relevant source, for example most modifiers on weapons.
- Added damage to attacks or spells from equipment and support gems.

• Damage Conversion

- Added as modifiers adds a percentage of one damage type as another damage type, for example

> Gain #% of Physical Damage as Extra Cold Damage during effect

or

> You and nearby allies add #% of your Physical Damage as Cold Damage.

- Converted to modifiers changes one type of damage into another, for example

> #% of Cold Damage Converted to Fire Damage.

• Global modifiers

- All increased and reduced modifiers are additive.
- All more and less modifiers are multiplicative.
  Converted damage can take benefit of bonuses for the damage type it was before and what it converted into.

•Critical strike roll
Hits can be rolled as a critical strike which multiplies the damage by 150% by default.

**2. Preventing the hit**

• Evasion of attacks.

• Dodge and Spell dodge.

**3. Damage Shift**

Incoming, damaging hits can be shifted to another damage type. It is usually done by utilizing an item which offers the

> #% of X Damage taken as Y modifier

*It is important to note that this is not damage conversion, as shifted part of damage does not retain its original damage property so it won't get mitigated either twice or by the more favorable method. For example, if some of the incoming damage is shifted to or from physical, the after-shift value is used in the armour calculation.*

**4. Damage Mitigation**

• Damage can be avoided, with some items or skill. Avoiding damage stops the damage of a hit. It still counts as a hit, even if it only is 0 damage.

• Elemental and chaos damage is mitigated by its respective resistance. ***( Here is where your Resistance's damage reduction take place. )***

• Physical damage is mitigated by the sum of all #% additional Physical Damage Reduction modifiers, up to its 90% cap.

**5. Damage Taken**

After damage mitigation, modifiers to damage taken are applied. Flat amounts are applied first, then the sum of all increases/reductions and lastly with more/less multipliers applied separately.

**5. Blocking the damage**

• Block and Spell block.

**6. Taking the final damage**

• All

> #% or # of Damage is Taken from # Before Life/Energy Shield

***( Here is where you Magna Eclipsis's Elemental Aegis take the damage for you. )***

• Non-chaos damage damages energy shield protecting life until it's depleted, by default.
For Mind over Matter users, #% of the remaining damage is removed from mana. Mind over Matter only applies if the damage is affecting life.

• Chaos damage always bypasses energy shield. This applies regardless if energy shield is protecting life or mana.

Comment: I know from from experience that aegis skills count after resistance, but I wanted to check the wiki for where it fits into the "taking a hit" MO but couldnt find anything about damage buffers from skills. Since your answer is so detailed, I don't suppose you have a source?

Comment: It's like MoM. The key mechanic is "#% of Damage Taken From x Before y" # Is the amount ( can be % or flat ), x is the effect/buff/item( Like MoM or Steelskin or an Aegis), and y is Life and or Energy Shield. Tbh I don't know if the wiki have this point clear, but the wording of the Aegis Skill is the same as MoM or Steelskin ( and in PoE wording is everything )

Comment: Huh, keen eye. I never considered the similarity. Actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your detailed answer! Going to accept it, but I didn't understand where you got all this info, from the wiki or elsewhere?

Comment: Official forum and wiki! Dev used to anserw a lot of questions regarding mechanics explaining how everything works.

Answer (score 1):

All four Aegis skills (Fire, Cold, Lightning, and Elemental) take resistances into account when absorbing damage.